# What HTML code is causing the empty white space here?

Tags: html, css

I have uploaded some webpages at a server which seems to add some extra stuff before it is rendered  ([link to page](http://packagex.hepforge.org/Documentation/HTML/X/ref/FermionLineExpand.html)).

One of the things I'm seeing is an empty white space near the top (see screen cap).

[image]

I am "inspecting source" to figure out if there is anything on my end that can be done to remove it.  But I can't even figure out what's causing it.  Can you find out which lines of HTML code is causing the white space?

Comment: Post the relevant code here directly so we can view it easily.

Comment: @Carcigenicate To be honest I don't know even which block of code is causing it.  Shall I post the html code for the whole page?  It's quite long.

Comment: Really, you should have tried you best to narrow down the problem before posting here. Post the code that you believe is relevent; although ideally you'd include a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.outer-wrapper {
    background: #f1f1f1 url(../images/background-gradient-subpage.png) repeat-x left top;

    /* padding-top: 30px; */

}
```

Try to remove `padding-top: 30px`

Comment: @QuantumDot no. you did commented `padding-top`. so you should remove or set be comment `padding-top`.

Comment: Ah, it worked!  Thanks.  There are 3 minutes before I can accept it.  In the meantime, would you tell me what tools you used to figure it out?

Comment: @QuantumDot I use `Google Chrome`. Try to search how to use `ctr+shift+i`.

Comment: @QuantumDot In modern browsers, you can press ctrl+F12 to open the developer console. Once there, there's usually an option to press an area of the screen, and see the relevent CSS and HTML. Clicking the whitespace area probably pointed to the padding of an element.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
 <div class="main-wrapper" style="height: auto;">
 <div class="outer-wrapper">
 <div class="breadcrumb">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <a href="../../X/guide/X.html">Mathematica</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper mainOuter">
```

Have you tried removing a wrapper?  The `div class="main-wrapper"` and `<div class="outer-wrapper">` seem to have the "same" dimensions, but main is larger than outer with the white space being the difference in appearance.

`<div class="wrapper mainOuter">` seems to also sit in the same "space" as `<div class="outer-wrapper">`.

I would try removing one or more of those wrappers and see if it behaves more as expected.